# Reenable hover after off jquery

Tags: jquery, binding, click, jquery-hover

I put together a simple fiddle to try to work out what I am trying to do. Basically I have an editor that the user can manipulate different elements on. When the user hover over an element that is editable a checkered outline appears via css. Once the user clicks the outline changes to a solid outline to indicate that this is the element that is now editable so I remove the hover event on the click so no if they move the mouse around the page not checkered lines appear around the other editable elements on the page, essentially locking them except for the one that is selected.

If the user decides not to edit that element I have a button that allows them to go back and"cancel" which reenables should hover for all the editable elements. So far I have been unable to get the event enabled again once I have it in a locked state.

Here is a fiddle 
http://jsfiddle.net/ZqfTX/276/

```
$('.element').on({
    mouseover: function(){
        $(this).css({'outline':'2px dashed red'});
    },
     mouseleave: function(){
        $(this).css({background: '#CCC'});
    },
    click: function(){
        $(this).off('mouseover');
        $(this).off('mouseleave');
        $(this).css({'outline':'2px solid #369fe4'});
    }
});

$('#button').click(function(){
      $('.element').on('mouseover');
      $('.element').on('mouseleave');

});
```

Can someone please take a look and let me know why I am unable to reenable the event using .on

Comment: You have to provide a handler function when you call `.on()`.

Comment: Instead of adding and removing event handlers, add and remove a class, and use event delegation to bind handlers to the class.

Comment: You can also use the class to change the CSS, instead of doing that in the handler.

Comment: Thanks changing the outline using clases is an easy fix. However, I am not sure what you mean by handler function can you provide an example?

Comment: `$('#button').on('click',function(){` has a handler function, `$('#button').on('mouseover');` doesn't.

Comment: Why are you trying to add `mouseover` and `mouseleave` to `#button`? Shouldn't it be added to the `.element` that you took the handler off of previously?

Comment: Yes you are right, I think in the process of testing different snippets I messed up what I originally had. $('#button').click(function(){
      $('.element').on('mouseover');
      $('.element').on('mouseleave'); 
       
});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reset the `function` you want to fire `on("mouseover")`

```
function setHover(){
    $('.element')
        .css({'outline':'none'})
        .off('mouseover mouseleave click')
        .on({
            mouseover: function(){
                $(this).css({'outline':'2px dashed red'});
            },
             mouseleave: function(){
                 $(this).css({'outline':'none', background: '#CCC'});
            },
            click: function(){
                $('.element').off('mouseover mouseleave click');
                $(this).css({'outline':'2px solid #369fe4'});
            }
        });
}

$('#button').click(function(){
   setHover();
});

setHover();
```

Comment: Thanks but that is not achieving the desired effect. Here is a fiddle [http://jsfiddle.net/ZqfTX/279/] http://jsfiddle.net/ZqfTX/279/ when you initially hover the boxes border turn red/checkerd. Once you click on one of the boxes the the hover toggles blue on the selected box and the hover effect should be disabled on the remaining boxes. Once the button "Cancel Editing" is clicked the originally selected element de-selects and the hover on the other elements in re enabled. Does that make sense? 

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes this makes sense. Let me see if I can figure it out.

Comment: I've updated it. Your initial question was about why you can't reattach a mouse on event, the reason is because 'off' completely removes that handlers function. Therefore you have to recreate the handler as well as the `mouseover` and `mouseleave`.  The functional problem was the `$(this).off` instead of `$('.element').off`

Comment: thanks. I looked at [jsfiddle.net/ZqfTX/279 ] and I did not see an update. Can you give me the new URL so I can review?

Comment: I see that now. Thanks! I wish I could buy you a cup of coffee.:-) I really appreciate your help with this.

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<div class="element inactive"></div>
<br>
<div id="button"><a href="#">Cancel Editing</a></div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).on({
    mouseleave: function(){
        $(this).css({background: '#CCC'});
    },
    click: function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('inactive active');
    }
}, '.element.inactive');

$('#button').on('click',function(){
      $('.element.active').toggleClass('inactive active');    
});
```

CSS:

```css
.element{
    position:absolute;
    top:60px;
    left:100px;
    background: #ccc;
    width: 200px;
    height: 120px;
}
.element.inactive:hover {
    outline: 2px dashed red;
}
.element.active {
    outline: 2px solid #369f34;
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/ZqfTX/255/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but this does not achieve what I am trying to do. In my real world situation there would be multiple boxes/ elements on the page. Once one of the elements is selected all the other elements on the page need to be locked. This means the the hover effects needs to be disabled once the element is selected. That  is why just switching the CSS is not enough. I need to turn the hover off using .off. Then if were to cancel editing the element, hit a button to re-bind the hover events of all the elements that I just disabled.

Does that make sense.

Comment: You can bind the hover effect to a specific class. When you select one of the elements, you change the class of the other elements, and then the hover effect will be disabled. If you make a fiddle showing your more general situation, I can show you.

Comment: I put together the fiddle you requested. Do you think that you can take a look and let me know how I can solve this issue? jsfiddle.net/ZqfTX/273 Thanks in advance.